# My 2013 Malibu electric park brake doesn't function and ''service'' sign comes on dash

Tags: chevrolet, malibu, parking-brake

2013 Malibu LTZ  ''service park brake switch'' stays on. mechanic thinks could be '' short to ground or open'' wire in switch. any experience out there? If I turn key only one notch it works fine, but when the instrument panel lights up it doesn't.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If there are codes (service sign is on), what is the exact code?

Comment: I'd probably ask your mechanic to check communications with the parking brake control module. I'm not sure if there's any causation between the key position and switch operation, as it looks like the parking brake control module is always hot and get's power from a fusible link. A code would help point in the right direction though. Was any work done to the brake system prior?